# Custom Message Box

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to create my own custom MessageBox where I would be able to add images instead of only strings?

Comment: you don't need to reinvent the wheel bro, i had the same idea to create my own but i searched and found a solution that fitted my needs as i have put it in the answer

Answer (score 35):

I also wanted this feature, so I created [**WPFCustomMessageBox**](https://github.com/evanwon/WPFCustomMessageBox), a WPF clone of the native Windows/.NET `MessageBox` which supports extra features like custom button text.

`WPFCustomMessageBox` uses static methods just like the standard .NET MessageBox, so you can **plug-and-play** the new library without modifying any code. Most importantly, I designed this control so it **looks identical to the original `MessageBox`**.

[image: WPFCustomMessageBox example]

I created this library because I wanted to use verbs for my MessageBox buttons to [help users better understand the functionality of the buttons](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/9960/12349). With this library, you can offer your users button descriptions like `Save/Don't Save` or `Eject Fuel Rods/Don't do it!` rather than the standard `OK/Cancel` or `Yes/No` (although you can still use those too, if you like).

The WPFCustomMessageBox message boxes return [standard .NET MessageBoxResults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messageboxresult%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It also offers the same features as the original `MessageBox` like `MessageBoxIcons` and custom message box captions.

WPFCustomMessageBox is open source, so you can grab the code or make improvements here: https://github.com/evanwon/WPFCustomMessageBox

You can add WPFCustomMessage to your project via NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPFCustomMessageBox/

Comment: +1 for the fuel rods... only thing missing: "spent"... "Spent Fuel Rods"! :P

Comment: Basic UI design principles say that you might want to make "Don't do it!" the default button, not the other one. ;-)

Comment: @Tenner Basic nuclear fuel rod principles probably agree with that as well :)

Comment: could it be used with winform C#?

Answer (score 10):

Here is the code needed to create your own message box:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyStuff
{
    public class MyLabel : Label
    {
        public static Label Set(string Text = "", Font Font = null, Color ForeColor = new Color(), Color BackColor = new Color())
        {
            Label l = new Label();
            l.Text = Text;
            l.Font = (Font == null) ? new Font("Calibri", 12) : Font;
            l.ForeColor = (ForeColor == new Color()) ? Color.Black : ForeColor;
            l.BackColor = (BackColor == new Color()) ? SystemColors.Control : BackColor;
            l.AutoSize = true;
            return l;
        }
    }
    public class MyButton : Button
    {
        public static Button Set(string Text = "", int Width = 102, int Height = 30, Font Font = null, Color ForeColor = new Color(), Color BackColor = new Color())
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Text = Text;
            b.Width = Width;
            b.Height = Height;
            b.Font = (Font == null) ? new Font("Calibri", 12) : Font;
            b.ForeColor = (ForeColor == new Color()) ? Color.Black : ForeColor;
            b.BackColor = (BackColor == new Color()) ? SystemColors.Control : BackColor;
            b.UseVisualStyleBackColor = (b.BackColor == SystemColors.Control);
            return b;
        }
    }
    public class MyImage : PictureBox
    {
        public static PictureBox Set(string ImagePath = null, int Width = 60, int Height = 60)
        {
            PictureBox i = new PictureBox();
            if (ImagePath != null)
            {
                i.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
                i.Location = new Point(9, 9);
                i.Margin = new Padding(3, 3, 2, 3);
                i.Size = new Size(Width, Height);
                i.TabStop = false;
                i.Visible = true;
                i.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(ImagePath);
            }
            else
            {
                i.Visible = true;
                i.Size = new Size(0, 0);
            }
            return i;
        }
    }
    public partial class MyMessageBox : Form
    {
        private MyMessageBox()
        {
            this.panText = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            this.panButtons = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // panText
            // 
            this.panText.Parent = this;
            this.panText.AutoScroll = true;
            this.panText.AutoSize = true;
            this.panText.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            //this.panText.Location = new Point(90, 90);
            this.panText.Margin = new Padding(0);
            this.panText.MaximumSize = new Size(500, 300);
            this.panText.MinimumSize = new Size(108, 50);
            this.panText.Size = new Size(108, 50);
            // 
            // panButtons
            // 
            this.panButtons.AutoSize = true;
            this.panButtons.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            this.panButtons.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
            this.panButtons.Location = new Point(89, 89);
            this.panButtons.Margin = new Padding(0);
            this.panButtons.MaximumSize = new Size(580, 150);
            this.panButtons.MinimumSize = new Size(108, 0);
            this.panButtons.Size = new Size(108, 35);
            // 
            // MyMessageBox
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(8F, 19F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new Size(206, 133);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panButtons);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panText);
            this.Font = new Font("Calibri", 12F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.Margin = new Padding(4);
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.MinimumSize = new Size(168, 132);
            this.Name = "MyMessageBox";
            this.ShowIcon = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();
        }
        public static string Show(Label Label, string Title = "", List<Button> Buttons = null, PictureBox Image = null)
        {
            List<Label> Labels = new List<Label>();
            Labels.Add(Label);
            return Show(Labels, Title, Buttons, Image);
        }
        public static string Show(string Label, string Title = "", List<Button> Buttons = null, PictureBox Image = null)
        {
            List<Label> Labels = new List<Label>();
            Labels.Add(MyLabel.Set(Label));
            return Show(Labels, Title, Buttons, Image);
        }
        public static string Show(List<Label> Labels = null, string Title = "", List<Button> Buttons = null, PictureBox Image = null)
        {
            if (Labels == null) Labels = new List<Label>();
            if (Labels.Count == 0) Labels.Add(MyLabel.Set(""));
            if (Buttons == null) Buttons = new List<Button>();
            if (Buttons.Count == 0) Buttons.Add(MyButton.Set("OK"));
            List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>(Buttons);
            buttons.Reverse();

            int ImageWidth = 0;
            int ImageHeight = 0;
            int LabelWidth = 0;
            int LabelHeight = 0;
            int ButtonWidth = 0;
            int ButtonHeight = 0;
            int TotalWidth = 0;
            int TotalHeight = 0;

            MyMessageBox mb = new MyMessageBox();

            mb.Text = Title;

            //Image
            if (Image != null)
            {
                mb.Controls.Add(Image);
                Image.MaximumSize = new Size(150, 300);
                ImageWidth = Image.Width + Image.Margin.Horizontal;
                ImageHeight = Image.Height + Image.Margin.Vertical;
            }

            //Labels
            List<int> il = new List<int>();
            mb.panText.Location = new Point(9 + ImageWidth, 9);
            foreach (Label l in Labels)
            {
                mb.panText.Controls.Add(l);
                l.Location = new Point(200, 50);
                l.MaximumSize = new Size(480, 2000);
                il.Add(l.Width);
            }
            Labels.ForEach(l => l.MinimumSize = new Size(Labels.Max(x => x.Width), 1));
            mb.panText.Height = Labels.Sum(l => l.Height);
            mb.panText.MinimumSize = new Size(Labels.Max(x => x.Width) + mb.ScrollBarWidth(Labels), ImageHeight);
            mb.panText.MaximumSize = new Size(Labels.Max(x => x.Width) + mb.ScrollBarWidth(Labels), 300);
            LabelWidth = mb.panText.Width;
            LabelHeight = mb.panText.Height;

            //Buttons
            foreach (Button b in buttons)
            {
                mb.panButtons.Controls.Add(b);
                b.Location = new Point(3, 3);
                b.TabIndex = Buttons.FindIndex(i => i.Text == b.Text);
                b.Click += new EventHandler(mb.Button_Click);
            }
            ButtonWidth = mb.panButtons.Width;
            ButtonHeight = mb.panButtons.Height;

            //Set Widths
            if (ButtonWidth > ImageWidth + LabelWidth)
            {
                Labels.ForEach(l => l.MinimumSize = new Size(ButtonWidth - ImageWidth - mb.ScrollBarWidth(Labels), 1));
                mb.panText.Height = Labels.Sum(l => l.Height);
                mb.panText.MinimumSize = new Size(Labels.Max(x => x.Width) + mb.ScrollBarWidth(Labels), ImageHeight);
                mb.panText.MaximumSize = new Size(Labels.Max(x => x.Width) + mb.ScrollBarWidth(Labels), 300);
                LabelWidth = mb.panText.Width;
                LabelHeight = mb.panText.Height;
            }
            TotalWidth = ImageWidth + LabelWidth;

            //Set Height
            TotalHeight = LabelHeight + ButtonHeight;

            mb.panButtons.Location = new Point(TotalWidth - ButtonWidth + 9, mb.panText.Location.Y + mb.panText.Height);

            mb.Size = new Size(TotalWidth + 25, TotalHeight + 47);
            mb.ShowDialog();
            return mb.Result;
        }

        private FlowLayoutPanel panText;
        private FlowLayoutPanel panButtons;
        private int ScrollBarWidth(List<Label> Labels)
        {
            return (Labels.Sum(l => l.Height) > 300) ? 23 : 6;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Result = ((Button)sender).Text;
            Close();
        }

        private string Result = "";
    }
}
```

This took me 2 days to write. I hope it works for anyone that needs it.

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented a WPF MessageBox fully customizable via standard WPF control templates:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2011/05/26/a-customizable-wpf-messagebox.aspx

**Features**

- The class WPFMessageBox has the exact same interface as the current WPF MessageBox class.
- Implemented as a custom control, thus fully customizable via standard WPF control templates.
- Has a default control template which looks like the standard MessageBox.
- Supports all the common types of message boxes: Error, Warning, Question and Information.
- Has the same “Beep” sounds as when opening a standard MessageBox.
- Supports the same behavior when pressing the Escape button as the standard MessageBox.
- Provides the same system menu as the standard MessageBox, including disabling the Close button when the message box is in Yes-No mode.
- Handles right-aligned and right-to-left operating systems, same as the standard MessageBox.
- Provides support for setting the owner window as a WinForms Form control.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. I've done it by subclassing [System.Windows.Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx) and adding the capacity to show various kinds of content (images, text and controls), and then calling [ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) on that Window:

```
public partial class MyMessageBox : Window
{
    // perhaps a helper method here
    public static bool? Show(String message, BitmapImage image)
    {
        // NOTE: Message and Image are fields created in the XAML markup
        MyMessageBox msgBox = new MyMessageBox() { Message.Text = message, Image.Source = image };
        return msgBox.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

In the XAML, something like this:

```
<Window>
    <DockPanel>
        <Image Name="Image" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
        <TextBlock Name="Message" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: didn`t work with me, in the var msgBox, Message and Image gives me errors!!

Comment: @sikas, you must be using Visual Studio 2005. The above syntax will work with the newer C# compiler in VS2008 and later. If you're stuck with VS2005, replace the "var msgBox..." line with three lines: "MyMessageBox msgBox = new MyMessageBox();", "msgBox.Message = message;", and "msgBox.Image = image;".

Comment: @silkas - whoops, sorry, I'm just so accustomed to C# 3.0 now... Joe is exactly right, and I've edited the answer to reflect his suggestions.

Comment: on VS2010, doesn't compile either way

Answer (score 0):

I was in need like you and I have found this source and modified the way I wanted and you could get the most benefit out of it

here is the [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327212/Custom-Message-Box-in-VC?fid=1684582)
this is what it looks like by default:

[image]