# Custom image enum for MessageBoxResult

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

I try to create a custom MessageBoxImage for the build in MessageBoxResult

For the custom MessageBoxImage enumeration, I have:

```
public enum CustomBoxImage
{
    Foo = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/MySoftware;component/Images/foo.png"))
}
```

and the MessageBoxResult, I have:

```
MessageBoxResult mrb = MessageBox.Show(
    "This will kill you. Are you sure?",
    "Kill you",
    MessageBoxButton.YesNo, CustomBoxImage.Foo);
```

But it gives me this error:

**Cannot convert from "...CustomBoxImage" to "System.Windows.MessageBoxImage'**

How can I insert a customized image enumeration into MessageBoxResult? Or, is it even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169996/c-wpf-custom-message-box

Comment: excuse me, how did you think it was ever supposed to work your solution? MessageBox.Show expects a value of the enum System.Windows.MessageBoxImage and you cannot jus pass whatever else you want!

Comment: @Davide: indeed this is kinda obvious

Comment: I don't think you can customize it, as Teoman said, use another window, then you have many more options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't customize the message boxes beyond the given options. If you need a fully customized one, you can use a 3rd party component. You can even make a window look fully like a message box and customize it if you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the signature of the Show method but you can create a converter between your enumeration and the MessageBoxImage enumeration.

if you want to use things that is not provide by the MessageBox, you can create your own messagebox.

Comment: but this is not what he needs, even a converter/mapper between enums will _not_ allow him to inject any other image and he will have to use the default ones anyway.