# How to customize MessageBox prompts?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress-wpf

This routine is widely used to prompt Yes/No confirmations to the end users:

```
var result = DXMessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, 
                                                   "Whatever", 
                                                  "Attention", 
                                    MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, ////////////// here
                                    MessageBoxImage.Question);

if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK) // then instead of this, it shall check some customized settings
{
    // confirmed for Orange for example
}
else
{
    // confirmed for Elephant for example
}
```

I don't want `YesNo`, `OKCancel` or the others. **How to customize the buttons**? I want the user to be able to do something similar to "*User presses a button, Application prompts two choices, User chooses one*". But I want to combine specified Choices, Texts and Sizes with the simplicity of a MessageBox?

**P.S** `DVMessageBox` and `System.Windows.MessageBox` are almost similar here.

Comment: Create your own dialog and customize them however you want. Alternatively: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16648605/752527

Comment: Message boxes are a very strong usability hazard.  Just about nobody actually reads them or understands what they try to say.  And they'll rarely pick anything but the default button and are commonly just annoyed at their modal behavior.  Limiting the number of valid responses is very much a feature and not a bug, be sure to not make it worse.

Comment: @Hanl This is one huge solution! Any other _simple_ approach?

Comment: @FirstStep Not that I can think of. That was just an example. Having your own dialogs (just a form, with buttons, and use `ShowDialog()` to open them, and some methods to use as callback) should not be too difficult.

Comment: @Hanl that is what I am exactly doing right now. Alright I will look at it and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view, you want just to create Custom control.
There are a lot articles:
[One](http://blogsprajeesh.blogspot.ru/2009/12/wpf-messagebox-custom-control.html)
[Two](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22511/WPF-Common-TaskDialog-for-Vista-and-XP)
[Three](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327212/Custom-Message-Box-in-VC?fid=1684582)

In addition , you can create `MessageBox` fully customizable via standard WPF control templates. Please, [see an example](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/arik/2011/05/26/a-customizable-wpf-messagebox/).